# Equivalent to navigateURL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I am currently redesigning an application which is written in ActionScript 3 in JavaScript. In the original ActionScript application, there is the use of the command navigateToURL to open a PHP script in the frame underneath the ActionScript application. Eg:

```
phpRequest.url = obj.action + ".php?param1=" + var1 + "&param2=" + var2 + "&param3=" + var3;
navigateToURL(phpRequest, "bottom");
```

Is there an equivalent function in JavaScript to open a PHP script underneath the current frame? Thank you.

Comment: What foes "underneath the current frame" mean in a browser?

Comment: Set the src of an iframe positioned under your content? Also what does the significance of PHP have to do with the question?

Comment: I have three frames under my window - header, top, and bottom. The bottom frame needs to display different content depending on the option selected by the user. Therefore I have used a PHP script to display that content.

Comment: `document.getElementById("iframe_id").src = "some_url";`

Comment: Thank you Marty - I'll try that and see how it goes.